# "Environment id is null or empty" error when posting an Adaptive Card to Teams as the flow bot with a Card Type Id

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

Using an Azure Logic App to post an adaptive card in a channel, I receive an error message "Environment id is null or empty" if I include the Card Type Id property.

I've had a similar issue in Power Automate, but it is usually solved by updating or replacing the connector.

When I change the connector in Logic Apps, the task is reset and I need to re-enter all properties.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

1. Initially created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. I got same error like you,

`"code": 400, "message": "Environment id is null or empty"`

[image]
[image]

3. Instead of using dynamic content from Get User Profile (V2), written expression as shown below,

`outputs('Get_user_profile_(V2)')?['Id']`

[image]

4. Logic app ran successfully as shown below,
   [image]

Comment: Thank you, this does run but when I inspect the Card Type Id of the completed run it is empty.
If you inspect the "Post adaptive card" is your Card Type Id also empty or does it indeed have the Id of the user profile in the previous step?

Comment: @sbitaxi - We did try this at our end, and we do see value in Card Type Id when we inspect "Post adaptive card".  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZN4e.png

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I never was able to get this to work. The screenshot you included appears to be from Power Automate and not a Logic App. 

I followed the exact steps that @vijaya provided but the Id is empty because the Id is a property of  the body `outputs('Get_user_profile_(V2)')?['body']?['id']` so without accessing the body property the Card Type Id is null and it submits.

When I do return an Id the Card Type Id is not null and it fails on submit
[Screenshot of Logic App and error](https://imgur.com/a/O2nC6ry)

Comment: Apologies for the delay, we are also able to repro this issue. We will raise a bug for the same.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT any update on this? I am still having this issue